# Visual studio query builder using filter

Tags: visual-studio-2010, builder

hi i have made a query but it is not giving any results, i am using 3 parameters cri,d1 and d2
i want to give values at run time, but when this query is executed no data is displayed even though i am giving correct input

```
SELECT  [Name Of District], 
    [ANC Id], 
    [Gram Panchayat or Village], 
    [Name Of Subcenter], 
    [Name Of PHC], 
    [Name Of Cluster], 
    [ANC Name], 
    EDD, 
    [2nd ANC], 
    [3rd ANC], 
    [4th ANC], 
    [TT Bosters]
FROM  [ANC Data]
WHERE ('@ cri' BETWEEN '@ d1' AND '@ d2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) tool to inspect the real SELECT statement with real WHERE parameters’ values.

Just execute the same SELECT statement within the [SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx) environment and check whether there is any data records satisfied to the SELECT query.

Comment: i am using a access data base